# how to protect mobile application with Registration Key?

Tags: java, java-me

i am developing mobile application and i want to protect it by using registration key , any idea how to that?

Answer (score 1):

How will the users register? If they're registering through your app, you can create a table that contains the device IDs of all the devices that have registered and check for activation in the database every time your app starts.

You could have two web services on the back end called -
`register(string deviceID)` and `checkActive(string deviceID)`.

Every time your app starts, in the main method you could call the `checkActive` method to see if the device is registered. If not you could redirect them to a registration screen.

Apple ofcourse will ban any such attempts, but since you've tagged it as Java, I'm assuming it's either Android or B'Berry, so you should be good.

Comment: the distribuition is to be done via content stores like getjar.com
i am not comfortable with enforcing the application to use internet connection each time it starts,i want to implement the  below scenario :
1- customer download the application from content store
2- a first run he will be prompted for registeration key or to use the app as demo for certain period of time
3- if he have the registration key he will type it and get it activated.
4- if demo period is expired he must pay for app
5-even if he reinstalled  the app he can never use in demo

Comment: Hmm, afraid I can't help you out in this case. Am interested to know the answer too.

But for (5) though, wouldn't deleting the app delete all its data too? How would you then check how long a user's used the app? Unless you tie it down to the email address and make a call to the server?

Comment: I too think you need a server to get it right, may be you can use sms messaging to check in case you dont want to use GPRS